# Why does Integrate have so much trouble evaluating my integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

Why are the answers for the following integrals different (the second one gives the correct answer)?

```
Integrate[(0.6090793168195031 - (2.2737783592977756*(30/
          49 + (156/49)*(-2 + 2*s) + (429/196)*(-2 + 2*s)^2))/(1 - 
        s)^(1/7))*
     (s/Sqrt[1 - s^2]), {s, 0, 1}]

Integrate[0.6090793168195031*(s/Sqrt[1 - s^2]), {s, 0, 1}] - 
   Integrate[((2.2737783592977756*(30/
          49 + (156/49)*(-2 + 2*s) + (429/196)*(-2 + 2*s)^2))/(1 - 
        s)^(1/7))*(s/Sqrt[1 - s^2]), 
     {s, 0, 1}]
```

P.S. I know that the numerical evaluation of the integral (NIntegrate) gives me the correct answer.

P.S.S. The version of my Mathematica is 10.4.0.0

Comment: Interesting. If you do a `FullSimplify` on the integrand of the first integral above, then it resolves to almost zero. If you leave the integrand as-is or just do a `Simplify` on it, you get 4.11 or so. If you `NIntegrate` it, you have to use "LocalAdaptive" method to avoid convergence warnings and get almost zero.  Odd things happen when you have zero in denominator.

Comment: But why do a numerical integral with `Integrate[]`?  It's not really designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
Integrate[
  s/Sqrt[1 - s^2]
    (Rationalize[0.6090793168195031] - 
      (Rationalize[2.2737783592977756] * 
        (30/49 + (156/49)*(-2 + 2*s) + (429/196)*(-2 + 2*s)^2)) / (1 -s)^(1/7)), 
  {s, 0, 1}]
```

gives

> `4.11522`

This gives the same result to your 1st integral and tells us that rationalization is being used by `Integral`.

To see why the integrals are so difficult to evaluate, we need only look at a plot to see the nasty singularities at `s = 1`.

```
expr1 = 0.6090793168195031*s/Sqrt[1 - s^2]
expr2 = 
  2.2737783592977756*(s/Sqrt[1 - s^2]*
    (30/49 + (156*(-2 + 2*s))/49 + (429*(-2 + 2*s)^2)/196))/(1 - s)^(1/7)
expr = expr1 - expr2;

Plot[{expr, expr1, expr2}, {s, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"expr", "expr1", "expr2"}]
```

[image: plot]

I would further argue that you can not trust any evaluation of your integral over the full domain `{0, 1}` as long as you have the two inexact coefficients 0.6090793168195031 and 2.2737783592977756 in the integrand. Because these coefficients are inexact, there will always be a interval of uncertainty in the neighborhood of 1. No matter how many digits in the coefficients are known, as long a they are inexact, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the value of integrand in the interval $(1-\epsilon,\,1]$ has no precision and its behavior can not be known.